# laravel Insert two array into the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hey guys I have to Arrays named $keys and $values Like this

```
keys
array:2 [▼
0 => "1"
1 => "2"
]

values
array:2 [▼
0 => "US"
1 => "Canada"
]
```

And I want to insert them to the database with my controller :

```
        $keys = $request->key;
    $values = $request->value;


    $datas  = new Collection();
    $datas->key_id = $keys;
    $datas->value = $values;
    $datas->product_id = $product_id;
    ProductSearchValuesModel::create($datas);
```

But this way is not working
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: show your form. Why do you have these items as separate keys and values in the request?

Comment: @Snapey in the form we duplicate inputs so values send like this : name="keys[]" , name="values[]"

Comment: Instead name them `items[]['key']` and `items[]['value']` then you will only have one array in the request and you can loop over it creating the ProductSearchValuesModel(s)

Answer (score 2):

It's better to change those array to jSon format. Please! check this code.

```
$datas  = new Collection();
$datas->key_id = json_encode($keys);
$datas->value = json_encode($values);
$datas->product_id = $product_id;
ProductSearchValuesModel::create($datas);
```

You'll have to use `json_decode($array, 1)` whenever you want to pull from database and use them. Also please check field length of that table ProductSearchValues to make sure it can hold that data.

Thanks